# Uncaught TypeError: : Return value must be of type array, bool returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form where users fill to add the amount to their account, in that form they will select a gateway (Paypal, perfect money, etc...) input an amount then send it to the functions I have designed in order to make the deposit. On submitting the form is sent to the controller and then create the process by choosing the right API to continue now this error is being thrown. Please need anyone help to fix  this, thanks in advance

error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: gatewayinfo(): Return value must be of type array, bool returned in C:\xampp\htdocs\model\gateways-model.php:86 Stack trace: #0
```

gateways Model

```
function gatewayinfo($gateway_id): array
{
    try {
        $db = createConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ays_gateways
                WHERE gatewayID = :gatewayID';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':gatewayID', $gateway_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $gatewayinfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //line 86
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $gatewayinfo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage()) ;
        return [];
    }
}
```

payment function

```
function getPaymentForm('51', gateway_id) {
    $gatewayInfo = gatewayinfo($gateway_id); ;
    $gateway = $gatewayInfo['name'];
    if($gateway == "PayPal") { return PF_PayPal('51',$gateway_id); }
    elseif($gateway == "Perfect Money") { return PF_PerfectMoney('51',$gateway_id); }
    else { return 'Something was wrong. Please try again.'; }
}
```

Comment: Check the code where you set up your PDO connection. I bet you haven't enabled exceptions after you create the PDO object. As to the error your code is returning: your query has failed. I leave how I know this as an exercise for the reader. (Hint: start by working out why you have a boolean instead of an array)

Comment: The question is in a form that it is of only very little or no use for future users. Once the problem has been understood, the far too generic, common error message combined with the individual code and the minimal fix-suggestion will not result in a useful contribution for future visitors. Instead, future visitors will be distracted by too much information as too many questions and answers do match a search for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem is in getPaymentFrom() function parameters. You have not declared the gateway_id variable correctly. that's why the function is returning bool. put the $ sign in front of gateway_id. follow the code below.

```
function getPaymentForm('51', $gateway_id) {
    $gatewayInfo = gatewayinfo($gateway_id); ;
    $gateway = $gatewayInfo['name'];
    if($gateway == "PayPal") { return PF_PayPal('51',$gateway_id); }
    elseif($gateway == "Perfect Money") { return PF_PerfectMoney('51',$gateway_id); }
    else { return 'Something was wrong. Please try again.'; }
}
```